# How to enable function to render templates based on try, except blocks from within another view in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-middleware

I am creating an application in **Django** that would allow my users to order items from my site based on information already stored in the database.

**Not all my users should be able to order certain items**, for this purpose I have written a pipeline with comparison statements and try, except blocks.

A small, reproduce-able piece of code looks like this:

## vendor.py

```
def guest_constraint(request)
    # Ensure user in request is a house-guest by checking if it has an active token.
    try:
        guest = GuestProfile.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'extGuest/appGuestError/not_hotel_login.html')

    # Check for Hotel Room Information linked to Guest Token
    try:
        room_information = RoomInformation.objects.get(guest_token=guest.token)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'extGuest/appGuestError/constraint_error.html')
```

## views.py

```
from .vendor import guest_constraint

@login_required
def index(request):
    guest_contraint(request)  # Filter out users with no access to this process.
    user = request.user  # Grab user defined in request.
    name = user.get_short_name()  # Grab first name of user.

    return render(request, 'extGuest/appGuestFlow/choose_order_type.html')
```

**Challenge:** I can successfully import this small script into my view and I can see its content is run **except** for the ***return render(request, template)*** part.

To explain myself better, the try/except block successfully catch the exception, however it does not returns the template specified in the block but instead it goes back to the view and renders the template I have in the view.

**What have I tried?** If I place the code of guest_constraint (vendor.py) and place it inside index (views.py) I see no problem and works as expected. This however doesn't scale well as I wish to call guest_contraint for many different functions in views.py

I'm fairly new to programming and Django and I still have lots to learn. If you could please give me a hint on what you think I'm doing wrong or what topic on Django (or even basic Python) could help me tackle this issue it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, I'm using **Django 1.11.6**.
**Edit 2:** Yikes, I forgot to include how I use the function in my index view. My bad, sorry.

## Solution:

Thanks to **@cwallenpoole** and some changes I did on his response I was able to edit my code to do what I wanted to do and it now looks like this:

## vendor.py | Updated

```
def guest_constraint(function):
    def _inner_guest_constraint(request)
        # This part should be familiar
        try:
            guest = GuestProfile.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'extGuest/appGuestError/not_hotel_login.html')

    try:
        room_information = RoomInformation.objects.get(guest_token=guest.token)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return render(request, 'extGuest/appGuestError/constraint_error.html')

    # Once all checks are passed return flow back to function.
    return function(request)

# return the wrapping
return _inner_guest_constraint
```

## views.py | Updated

```
from .vendor import guest_constraint

@login_required
@guest_constraint
def index(request):
    user = request.user  # Grab user defined in request.
    name = user.get_short_name()  # Grab first name of user.

    return render(request, 'extGuest/appGuestFlow/choose_order_type.html')
```

Comment: I don't see the `guest_constraint` method used in your `index` view.

Comment: Apologies for that, I accidentally omitted how I use the function within the views.py function. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you might want to consider using an annotation instead of just as a function:

```
def guest_constraint(fn):
    def _inner_guest_constraint(request)
        # This part should be familiar
        try:
            guest = GuestProfile.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return render(request, 'extGuest/appGuestError/not_hotel_login.html')

        try:
            room_information = RoomInformation.objects.get(guest_token=guest.token)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return render(request, 'extGuest/appGuestError/constraint_error.html')

        # Call the wrapped function
        fn(request)

    # return the wrapping
    return _inner_guest_constraint
```

Then you could simply annotate:

```
@login_required
@guest_constraint
def index(request):
```

You could also modify it so that your wrapping function adds parameters:

```
def guest_constraint(fn):
    def _inner_guest_constraint(*args,**kwargs):
        # stuff
        kwargs.update({'guest':guest, 'room_info': room_information})
        fn(*args,**kwargs)
    return _inner_guest_constraint
```

That would mean that you'd need to make sure that your annotated views took guest and room_info params, but it would also mean that you're defining variables once.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for this response. I've tried to implement it and I feel this is the way I want to go with. I somehow have an error. It seems that when the requests go through all these filters (because the user is eligible to do this) Django throws a NoneType exception. Do you know of a way for the guest_constraint annotation to return the flow back into the views.py function so that I can render a template of my liking as long as the guest passes these constraints? Considering as well I would really like to use this annotation across all my views.

Comment: Disregard message above. I was able to edit the code where it needed to be edited. Thank you for your time to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample views.py doesn't show anything using guest_constraint, just the import. It sounds like you want something in the middle of index (and other views) that will check guest_constraint. One simple way to handle it is to return two values - a result status and the render() results. Add `False` to each of the existing `return render()` lines and at the end of the function return `True, None`. Full function becomes:

```
def guest_constraint(request)
    # Ensure user in request is a house-guest by checking if it has an active token.
    try:
        guest = GuestProfile.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return False, render(request, 'extGuest/appGuestError/not_hotel_login.html')

    # Check for Hotel Room Information linked to Guest Token
    try:
        room_information = RoomInformation.objects.get(guest_token=guest.token)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return False, render(request, 'extGuest/appGuestError/constraint_error.html')

    # Everything is good
    return True, None
```

and in views.py you could have:

```
constraint_ok, constraint_render = guest_constraint(request)
if not constraint_ok:
    return constraint_render
```

Comment: Thanks for this mate. I decided to opt using the other response that does the same with annotations.